# Boyer-Moore-Algorithm: to pass a character

Tags: string-matching

In the [original abstract](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/publications/fstrpos.pdf) of the Boyer-Moore-algorithm the phrase *to pass a character* often occurs. What does this phrase mean exactly? I am not a native english speaker and google results are not helpful.

I am asking this question on this board, because the context might seem important.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm has two loops: an outer loop over potential matching substrings and an inner loop over the characters of each potential matching substring.

Consider searching for "BIG" in string "FROGBIG".

The outer loop iterates over potential locations that "BIG" might occur - in FROGBIG, there are (at most) 5 such locations.

```
12345
FROGBIG
BIG     (outer loop index=1)
  BIG   (outer loop index=3)
```

For each comparison, the inner loop iterates over the characters of the pattern.  So for outer loop index of 1, the inner loop will compare "BIG" and FRO" iterating over the string BIG, backwards, one character at a time (at most, 3 comparison).

```
123
ORF
GIB
G   (inner loop index = 1)
  B (inner loop index = 3)
```

The algorithm (which I won't get into) is optimizing these loops so as to avoid needless comparisons.  That is, during the comparison of FRO and BIG (outer loop 1), the inner loop will only compare "G" vs "O" (inner loop 1), not "R" vs "I" (inner loop 2) or "B" vs "F" (inner loop 3).  Furthermore, after comparing "FRO" to "BIG", the outer loop will skip over ROG vs BIG (outer loop 2) and OGB vs BIG (outer loop 3), moving immediately to GBI vs BIG (outer loop 4).

It is in discussing the inner loop (over "G", "I", and "B") that the authors first make use of the word "pass".  When the authors say "pass a character", "character" is referring to individual characters "G", "I", and "B" over which the inner loop iterates.  The word "pass" is used in the same way I might give street directions: "You will pass Oak Street and pass Maple Street to get to Olive Street".  But instead of passing streets, the authors are describing "passing characters": "You will pass G and pass I to get to B".

To further clarify, the authors also frequently use the word "pass" as the adjective "passed".  So, they often refer to a "passed character".  In this case, "passed characters" are just the characters that the inner loop had to check (or "pass by") to get to the current character.  In my street directions, once the traveler reaches Olive Street, one would call Oak Street and Maple Street "passed streets".  In the algorithm, if the inner loop is at "I", then "G" is a "passed character"; if it is at "B" then the "passed characters" refers to both "G" and "I".

Finally, the authors continue using the convention "passed characters" in analyzing the overall efficiency.  From the paper, "By dividing the number of references to string by the number of characters i - 1 passed before the pattern was found".  Here, I believe they're referring to the number of characters in the search string which had to be passed over before the pattern was found.  If I'm not mistaken, this seems a bit oblique: the "number of characters passed" is really just "the position of the first occurrence of the pattern in the string".  Thus, in fig 1, efficiency is really measured as, "for a pattern of a certain length (3 for "BIG"), what % of the potential matching strings (5 for "FROGBIG": FRO, ROG, OGB, GBI, and BIG) did the algorithm check?"

Answer (score 0):

your link already rephrases the "pass more characters than it examines" as follows:

Thus, the algorithm has the unusual property that, in most cases, not all of the first "i" characters of "string" are inspected.

I.O.W.: Not all characters passed to the algorithm are necessarily inspected.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

"Pass a character" in this context is closer to "skipping" a character, or not inspecting it.

The following pseudo-code "passes" odd-indexed characters in the `char` array

```
char[] charArray = ['a','b','c', ...];

// increment by 2 to "pass" every other character
for (int i=0; i<charArray.Length; i+=2)
{
    Print(charArray[i]);
}
```

EDIT: while the above is true in many contexts, in the context of the link you provided this is NOT how it is used (as was pointed out to me by @KevinKirkpatrick)

In brief, a "passed character" in the context of the link you provided means "any character that will not be inspected in the future".

In other words, if you are looping through an array by incrementing (and not decrementing) an index then "passed" characters are all characters that are at a lower index than your current index.  This means "passing a character" at index `i` means incrementing your index to be greater than `i`.

Comment: I'm not sure this captures the authors' meaning.  Note, particularly, how they reference "passed characters" as the denominator in determining efficiency.  A search pattern of 1 character would make it impossible to "skip" checking any character.  So the number of skipped characters would be 0.  If "passed" were used synonymously with "skipped characters", then DIV0 errors would show up in their efficiency calculations.

Comment: @KevinKirkpatrick I don't think they are worried about efficiency of algorithms or what sort of effect on the algorithm that passing characters has.  They just didn't understand what the phrase meant.  This was the basis for my shorter answer and why I thought it was good for the OP

Comment: Right - what I meant was, the authors use the terminology "passed character" in describing efficiency.  If the OP interprets "passed character" as "characters that were skipped / not used", then the authors' explanation of efficiency measures will not make sense.  In your pseudo code, the authors would call ALL characters in your array "passed characters"; i.e. "John Carpenter's algorithm will not examine all of the characters that it passes; half of them will be skipped"

Comment: That's not to say your usage of "pass" is wrong; it's a perfectly valid way to use the word "pass".  It's just not the way the authors of the paper seem to use it.   With your array, if your array had 26 characters and the for loop had an end condition of i < 6, then a, b, c, d, e, and f would be "passed", with a, c, and e being "examined" and b, d, and f being "skipped".  Thus, their measure of efficiency, basically described as "examined characters" / "passed characters", would be 3/6, not 3/3.

Comment: @KevinKirkpatrick thanks for pointing this out.  I have edited my post to fix it :)

Comment: Okay, I thought I would get a notification for comments, so sorry for my late reply ... but to sum it up now: If I have abcd as text and 01 as pattern, written left-aligned under my text. After comparing 0 with a, I shift 01 so that it is written right-aligned under my text. Then I have inspected the character a in the text, skipped the character b, but passed the characters ab?

Comment: @Christian Do you have any other questions about what "passing characters" means?